# Is there a way to create a filter in view to display only the 'New Item' in a library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view

Is there's a way to create a view that filters only the new files in a library? In SharePoint Online an icon displays next to the filename, when a new item is created/uploaded (see image).

What data does this icon use in order to display next to new files/items?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if there is any column for this indicator in the document library but you can filter the view by Created column in descending order to show the latest created/uploaded documents at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what SharePoint uses to display that "new item" icon. But you could create a view with a filter on the created column and set it to

- "is greater or equal to"
- "[today]-{numberOfDays}"

Then the view will only display documents that were created in the last x amount of days.

[image: filter screenshot]

Comment: It's a good solution, thank you, but if a library doesn't get used very often, the newest item in that library might be over 30 days.  I don't know how long that 'new item' icon lasts next to a file/item, it may have a limited amount of days.